# How to show that $\mathbb{G}_a$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$ are connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be a field and $\mathbb{A}^1$ the affine line. Let $\mathbb{G}_a$ be the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ with group law $\mu(x, y)=x+y$. Let $\mathbb{G}_m$ be the affine open subset $K^* \subset \mathbb{A}^1$ with group law $\mu(x,y)=xy$. How to show that $\mathbb{G}_a$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$ are connected? I think that we have to show that $\mathbb{G}_a$ (resp. $\mathbb{G}_m$) is not the union of two disjoint proper closed subsets of $\mathbb{G}_a$ (resp. $\mathbb{G}_m$). Here $\mathbb{G}_a$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$ are considered as algebraic groups. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand. They are both irreducible. The coordinate ring of one is $K[x]$ and the other is $K[x,y]/(xy-1)$ which are both integral domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that a ring $R$ is said to be connected if $R$ doesn't contain any idempotent besides $0$ and $1$. It's a classical result that an affine variety is connected if and only if its coordinate ring is connected as an algebra (you can easily find this on google).

The coordinate rings of $G_a$ and $G_m$ are $K[X]$ and $K[X,Y]/(XY-1)$, respectively. Those are integral domains, and of course an integral domain is connected (check). Ask if you need more details.

Comment: thank you very much. How to compute the coordinate rings of $G_a, G_m$?

Comment: Any morphism of $K$-algebra from $K[X]$ to another one, say, $B$ is uniquely determined by the image of $X$. In particular you get a bijection between $Hom_K(K[X],B)$ and $B$. In the same way you get a bijection between $Hom_K(K[X,Y]/(XY-1),B)$ and the set $B^{\times}$ of invertible elements in $B$, since such a morphism is etermined by the image of $X$ which should lie in $B^{\times}$.